# Filtered (not printed-out) logging and performance in Java

Tags: java, logging

I know that logging can severely hamper the application's performance. I'm wondering if the impact of logging on the app's performance would be also noticeable if all logging were filtered by using an appropriate LoggingFilter.

I'm wondering about this because I'm considering implementing logging in my application, since it could be extremely useful, but not at the expense of (possibly) making it slow.

Comment: *Premature optimization is the root of all evil*. Before finding a solution for a problem you don't have yet, you should first add logging and see if that is a problem.

Comment: Just a comment, not an answer. I wouldn't expect any performance problems with logging.

Comment: If you want to have a simple logging solution, you could have a static boolean variable in the logger that can be set to true or false in a static block (example, reading the value from a configuration file). In your logging methods, you just have to check if the boolean is true before doing the actual logging (such a check is inexpensive). String concat can be avoided by using Object varargs (concat only if boolean is true). A more sophisticated logging solution can actually create a cleaned duplicate of your source code with the logging statements removed before compilation.

Comment: For multiple levels of logging, use several static booleans or a static `short` variable (this only takes half the bits of int and is more than sufficient to describe different levels). Btw, the logging level check should be done inside the logger. It's just really messy and ugly to do it outside in your production code (as suggested by the code snippet in Raibaz's answer).

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, logging is usually (i.e. by your usual [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) implementation) done in a separate thread, so it doesn't actually impact your performances that much.

Something I have learned to avoid performance hits when adding logging is to always check if the appropriate logging level is enabled before doing any string concatenation to build log messages, that is:

```
if(log.isInfoEnabled()) {
    log.info("This log message has some string concatenation " + loggedValue);
}
```

This way, if the logging level treshold is set to something higher than INFO, you will not run the string concatenation.

Comment: Uhm... thank you sir for your answer, but I don't think it answers my question.